# Postfixadmin Kubernetes Debian 12

Tags: postfix, kubernetes

I have setup a kubernetes cluster on debian 12(first time), and i used the docker mailserver project to install the pods.

So far so good, but now I can't seem to expose the 80 or 443 to a network that's reachable from the host and/or internet.

My services

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postfixadmin
  namespace: mailserver
spec:
  selector:
    app: mailserver
    tier: postfixadmin
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

---

My deployment

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postfixadmin
  namespace: mailserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mailserver
      tier: postfixadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mailserver
        tier: postfixadmin
        logType: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postfixadmin
        image: technicalguru/mailserver-postfixadmin
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: PFA_DB_HOST
          value: "mariadb"
        - name: PFA_DB_NAME
          value: "mail"
        - name: PFA_DB_USER
          value: "postfix"
        - name: PFA_DB_PASS
          value: "<my-mariadb-postfix-password>"
        - name: PFA_SETUP_PASS
          value: "<my-postfixadmin-setup-password>"
        - name: PFA_POSTFIX_SERVER
          value: "postfix"
        - name: PFA_POSTFIX_PORT
          value: "25"
        - name: PFA_ABUSE_EMAIL
          value: "<my-abuse-email-address>"
        - name: PFA_HOSTMASTER_EMAIL
          value: "<my-hostmaster-email-address>"
        - name: PFA_POSTMASTER_EMAIL
          value: "<my-postmaster-email-address>"
        - name: PFA_WEBMASTER_EMAIL
          value: "<my-webmaster-email-address>"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
```

---

When i describe the pod i get this

```
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.55.82
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.55.82
    Port:           80/TCP
        Host Port:      0/TCP
        State:          Running
```

Why is the host port zero?

---

I have tried NodePort or LoadBalancer in my services but that didn't work
I have these routes on the worker node

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp
src 10.0.0.5 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope l
ink src 10.0.0.5 metric 100
10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link s
rc 10.0.0.5 metric 100
168.63.129.16 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto
 dhcp src 10.0.0.5 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 pro
to dhcp src 10.0.0.5 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel sc
ope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.6.64/26 via 10.0.0.4 dev tunl0 pr
oto bird onlink
blackhole 192.168.55.64/26 proto bird
192.168.55.65 dev cali8fb4941a749 scope l
ink
192.168.55.66 dev cali412dc594ad1 scope l
ink
192.168.55.67 dev calife0a454e65c scope l
ink
192.168.55.68 dev cali39db290e63b scope l
ink
192.168.55.70 dev cali0d3689f40c9 scope l
ink
192.168.55.72 dev cali9f9b29a13b3 scope l
ink
192.168.55.73 dev cali2e3727ded1f scope l
ink
192.168.55.75 dev cali6f24beac01c scope l
ink
192.168.55.82 dev cali7040637c394 scope l
ink
```